# Can not install Jruby using RVM

Tags: rvm, ubuntu-12.10

When I run one of the following commands:

```
rvm install jruby-1.7.3
```

or

```
rvm install jruby
```

I get the following message:

> Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
>
> Installing requirements for ubuntu, might require sudo password.
>
> Running 'apt-get --quiet --yes update' would require sudo.
>
> Cowardly refusing to continue, please read 'rvm autolibs'.
>
> Updating repositories
>
> Missing required packages: git-core.
>
> Cowardly refusing to continue, please read 'rvm autolibs'.

and

> rvm --version

gives me

> rvm 1.19.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin ,
>   Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]

Could anyone advise how to fix this?

Comment: the command asked you to read `rvm autolibs` - did you?

Comment: @mpapis Actually doing this and looking thought the output solve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was fixed with just running:

```
rvm autolibs enabled
```

When I firstly run

```
rvm autolibs status
```

and the output was "disabled", where allowed modes are as follows:

- `0`, `disable`, `disabled`          - Limit RVM automation as much as possible.
- `1`, `read`, `read-only`            - Allow RVM to use package manager if found but do not install or fail if dependencies are missing.
- `2`, `fail`, `read-fail`            - Allow RVM to use package manager if found, fail if dependencies are missing. This is **default**.
- `3`, `packages`, `install-packages` - Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies.
- `4`, `enable`, `enabled`            - Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies, install package manager (only OSX).
- `brew`, `homebrew`, `osx_brew`      - Like `4` but forces use of Homebrew.
- `port`, `macports`, `osx_port`      - Like `4` but forces use of MacPorts.
- `fink`, `osx_fink`                  - Like `4` but forces use of Fink.
- `smf`                               - Like `4` but forces use of SM Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need to install git `sudo apt-get install git`

Comment: I have installed it but the error messages appears again.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error when installing ruby

> Missing required packages: git.
>
> Cowardly refusing to continue, please read 'rvm autolibs'.

Take a look at the instructions on the following link, it may help you.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-centos-6-with-rvm

Note that after installing rvm you probably have to install additional dependencies using following command before you install ruby (this is listed in the link)

`yum install -y gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel zlib zlib-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel make bzip2 autoconf automake libtool bison iconv-devel`

NOTE: For centos >= 5.4 iconv-devel is provided by glibc